# Generate a radio button in JQUery

Tags: jquery

Multiple Choices

onclick of this radio i am trying to generate a radio button with two choices .. How to do so in JQUery??

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you really meant "radio", but if you did, maybe you want something as simple as:

```
$("#radio").click(function(){
    $("#myRadioContainerSelector").html("<input type='radio' id='yes' name='myRadio' value='yes' /><label for='yes'>Yes</label><input type='radio' id='no' name='myRadio' value='no' /><label for='no'>No</label>");
});
```